# Не воспроизводится mp4 в браузере Opera на Arch Linux

Tags: linux, webbrowser, браузер, opera, mp4

Ни на одном сайте не воспроизводятся mp4-файлы. В чем может быть причина?

Прочитал, что раньше опера не поддерживала этот формат вообще, но с версии 52 это, якобы, поправили.

P.S. Firefox отлично воспроизводит любые видео на этой же машине.

```
 OS: Arch Linux x86_64
 GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620
 Opera: 55.0.2994.44
```

Comment: mp4-файлы бывают очень разные, всё зависит от формата конкретного файла

Comment: @andreymal Я понимаю, но не воспроизводятся вообще никакие.

Comment: Хм, попробовал сам — и правда

Comment: @andreymal Может попробовать во флагах покопаться? Правда, я там ничего насчет mp4 не находил.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/html5 пишет, что поддержки H.264 (того, что внутри MP4) в опере нету, такие дела

Comment: И да, во флагах надо искать h264, потому что mp4 — это просто контейнер, в котором может быть много всяких разных форматов (хотя во флагах я тоже ничего интересного не вижу)

Comment: @andreymal Да, точно. Вот что нашел: "WebRTC H.264 software video encoder/decoder". Стоит в положении Default.

Comment: `pacman` подсказывает мне, что в Arch Linux есть ещё пакет `opera-ffmpeg-codecs` — после его установки у меня всё заработало

Comment: @andreymal Поставил эти кодеки, но ничего не изменилось :( Где вы проверяете работоспособность?

Comment: Попробуйте этот файл http://home.andreymal.org/files/mp4test.mp4

Comment: @andreymal Да, попробовал, не работает.

Comment: Ну это уже совсем странно. В моей опере на моём арче он работает. Браузер не забыли перезапустить после установки?

Comment: @andreymal И браузер, и машину перезапускал. Результат, к сожалению, один. Может быть мне не хватает обычных кодеков h.264 каких-нибудь? Или оперовские должны сами по себе работать?

Comment: Даже не знаю, попробуйте просто ffmpeg установить, если он вдруг не установлен

Comment: @andreymal Проверил, у меня установлен на данный момент libx264.

Comment: @andreymal Вообще, как я понял, все нужные кодеки у меня установлены.

Comment: @andreymal Помогло полное обновление всех кодеков. Проблема решена, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Установка пакета `opera-ffmpeg-codecs` должна решить проблему

```bsh
sudo pacman -Sy opera-ffmpeg-codecs
```